# Rewrite Rule to Combine Taxonomy and Post Type

Tags: posts

I have a website, https://www.mysteryperu.tours, with three Custom Post Types listed below:

- departamento
- provincia
- destino

Under the `destino` Custom Post Type, I have two custom fields: *ACF*, and *Advanced Custom Fields*.

The *Departamento* Type Post Object has a relation with the Custom Post Type, *departamento*.

Provincia (Type Post Object):Is related to the custom post type “provincia”

I want to achieve the following: website/departamento/provincia/name-destino

```
destino = paredones
departamento = ica
provincia= nasca
website/ica/nasca/paredones
```

I hope you can help me and teach me the right way to order my permalink

Answer (score 0):

We need to create the WordPress rewrite rule to handle multi-level slugs such as:

```
function cpt_rewrite_rule($wp_rewrite) {
    $rules = array();
    $terms = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy_name',
        'hide_empty' => false,
    ) );

    $post_type = 'post_type_name';
    foreach ($terms as $term) {

        $rules['parent_slug_name/' . $term->slug . '/([^/]*)$'] = 'index.php?post_type=' . $post_type. '&post_type_name=$matches[1]&name=$matches[1]';

    }
    // merge with global rules
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_filter('generate_rewrite_rules', 'cpt_rewrite_rule');
```

This filter will be called when flushing rewrite rules. I recommend you go to Settings > Permalinks and just save them once again to flush the rewrite rules.